# How does one configure the Microsoft Message Analyzer on a Windows 10 workstation to trace EWT messages from IIS 8.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2?

Tags: windows-10, iis-8.5

I'm trying to trace ETW messages using the Microsoft Message Analyzer.

In my searching I found [this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/701712/can-the-etw-provider-microsoft-windows-iis-logging-be-installed-on-a-windows-wo) about how to configure it on Windows 7:

But I do not understand the following steps:

1. Verify that the `MessageFileName` and `ResourceFileName` file of iisres.dll is already on your Windows workstation.
2. Export both of these registry keys to .reg files and import them to your Windows workstation.
3. Launch Message Analyzer as a local admin on your Windows workstation, and verify that Microsoft-Windows-IIS-Logging is available as a Provider.

How do I verify that the `MessageFileName` and `ResourceFileName` file of iisres.dll are already on my workstation (are these sub files inside the iisres.dll)?

Which registry keys do I export/import from the server and to the workstation?

And how do I verify that the provider is in Message Analyzer?

Comment: My apologies if this question belongs somewhere, else like stackoverflow, if it does, please move it there.

Comment: run [perfview to capture the events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54114220/1466046): `PerfView /OnlyProviders=Microsoft-Windows-IIS-Logging`